# Copying a file using Inno Setup after the installation completed

Tags: apache, inno-setup, httpd.conf

I am installing the Apache through the Inno Setup. Now I want to copy the `httpd.conf` file from my local disk to Apache `conf` folder after the Apache installation.
How can I achieve this using Inno Setup?

Comment: If Apache is a prerequisite of your app you might want to consider using `PrepareToInstall` to install it instead of `[Run]` (see the example script).  It's a little more work but you get a lot more control over things.

Comment: Related question: [Overwrite installed files with files in setup subfolder in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65161551/850848).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved this issue by using the `AfterInstall` parameter in `[Run]` section. It works fine.

Answer (score 3):

you can use my code to copy your httpd.conf file to Apache conf folder,try it:)

```
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
if CurStep = ssDone then
begin
//copy your httpd.conf file from your localdisk to Apache conf folder
FileCopy('/you/path/httpd.conf','/apache/conf/httpd.conf',False);
end;
```

Comment: Though this will work, the `ssDone` step is the very last step of the setup and that is unecessarily late. Better use `ssPostInstall` step. But this will better be executed from the `PrepareToInstall` event where you run the Apache setup and after that copy the file. Also keep in mind that not everything has to be executed from a `[Code]` section event method. OP e.g. mentioned using `[Run]` section and for that you would better write an `AfterInstall` parameter function. Btw. you're having typo in your code (missing comma) ;-)